# Close all child threads WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a Window in WPF and user can start very long operations on it. User must be able to cancel those operations.

All of my operations are in separate threads. So my question is:
Can I terminate all threads that are started from that Window, without killing UI thread obviously, at any time?

On places where I need to do long operations threads were created and started like this

```
 Thread thread =
            new Thread(
                new ThreadStart(
                    delegate
                    {...}));
        thread.Start();
```

How to pass that object to it? is it possible? If it is important at all I do not care about graceful closing of threads, they can be killed, it would still be a solution. Is window object aware of threads to whom it is parent?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you start the threads?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Refer [Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I create thread object, and than I .start() it

Answer (score 0):

Typically you won't want to create/destroy threads. There's much more overhead when creating a Thread every time you need one than there is in thread pools and Tasks (This applies, like specified, when you need to create a significant number of Threads in the lifetime of your processes).

The preferred approach (especially if you're using .Net 4.0, or even better 4.5) is to use Tasks.

There's is tons of documentation on how to use Tasks, and how to cancel them. @xxbbcc posted a link in a comment on your question.

However, if you still think that dealing with Threads is your best choice, you could keep a track of all the threads. Then whenever you (as a developer) or your user determines they want to kill the thread, you can just iterate through the threads and call the `Abort()` method on them.

```
public class MyExampleClass
{
  private List<Thread> MyThreads { get; set; }

  public MyExampleClass()
  {
    MyThreads = new List<Thread>();
    InstanciateThreadsWithSomeSuperImportantOperations();
  }
  private void InstanciateThreadsWithSomeSuperImportantOperations()
  {
    var thread = new Thread();
    // some code here 

    MyThreads.Add(thread);
  }

  public void KillAllThreads()
  {
    foreach (var t in MyThreads)
    {
      if (t.IsAlive)         
        t.Abort(); // Note this isn't guaranteed to stop the thread.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Don't recommend `Abort` please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561976/check-if-thread-finished-its-method-before-killing-it-c-sharp/27562048#27562048)

Comment: Using abort or not is another issue here. Of course I can create a list of threads and kill them all, and it looks that i will have to do exactly that.

It is actually my question - can i do it without manually having to watch about threads that are running(have they stopped, remove them from list etc...). 

And of course if i can do it without a massive refactoring of my code

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm trying to not recommend using Threads at all, but I don't see another way to kill a thread.

Comment: There exist a way, it is right there in the link I provided. Use TPL with cancellation token if .net 4.0 or greater. Otherwise use a volatile flag and check it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel as I see, this link explains what is wrong with answer Cameron provided, but unfortunately it does not answer my needs.

Comment: @Rouz It explained it. Please read *Let the thread decide when it should complete* section. If you need code help, please provide your code.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel no it did not answer my question. You obviously are right, but that is not what I asked. Question is, is a Window aware of it's children threads? If it is, I will close them as I please (like you said ofc). But if not i have to do massive refactoring and modifications - which i tried to avoid.

Comment: @Rouz *is a Window aware of it's children threads* Answer is no. Window doesn't know about threads, not it should. So you need to keep a list of threads you create.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ok, put it like answer if you want me to accept it. Thanks